# How can I omit unintended lines in a plot?

Tags: plotting

I use listlineplot to plot some datasets and I don't know why a horizontal line appears in the plot which is when U is approximately 5. I want to omit the line which in the output of the below lines

```
    L = 20;

lst1 = {0.01564344653109275, 0.030901699458882034, 
   0.04539904998944419, 0.05877852523891589, 0.07071067812285757, 
   0.08090169943684067, 0.08910065241415929, 0.09510565162182796, 
   0.09876883404996432, 0.0999999999898204, 0.09876883404996355, 
   0.09510565162182645, 0.08910065241415803, 0.08090169943683993, 
   0.07071067812285665, 0.05877852523891543, 0.04539904998944429, 
   0.03090169945888173, 0.015643446531092838` };
p1 = ListLinePlot[-2 Log[lst1/Total[lst1]], DataRange -> {1, L - 1}/L,
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thickness[0.003]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"q = r = 2"}];

lst2 = {0.010814123835564406, 0.02131436441316639, 
   0.03830237328244655, 0.05417864410963838, 0.06848236330194081, 
   0.08079836105637143, 0.09076916178965738, 0.09810535997584019, 
   0.10259402022974776, 0.10410485782135909, 0.10259402022974679, 
   0.09810535997583723, 0.09076916178965475, 0.08079836105636874, 
   0.06848236330193896, 0.05417864410963691, 0.0383023732824455, 
   0.021314364413165778, 0.010814123835564201` };
p2 = ListLinePlot[-2 Log[lst2/Total[lst2]], DataRange -> {1, L - 1}/L,
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.003]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"q < r (q = 1.2 , r = 3.5)"}];

Show[{p1, p2}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, L - 1}/L, {4.5, 10}}, PlotLabel -> "L = 20", 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(l\), \(L\)]\)", 14, Bold], 
   Style["U", 14, Bold]}]
Export["L20.pdf", %, ImageSize -> 100]
```

How can I do that? What is it there for?

Comment: What happens if you add `Axes -> None`?

Comment: It doesn't help!

Comment: The problem appears to be restricted to the p1 plot.

Comment: I think you want `Axes->False` on the `p1` plot

Comment: Setting `Axes -> False` within the `Show` command also works.  Evidently, `Frame -> True` does not automatically override the `Axes - True` option carried by `p1` into `Show`. Instead, the `Axes` and `Frame` commands somehow interact to create the spurious horizontal line.  I think this is a bug.

Comment: @bb, it's not really a bug; just something that the user doesn't want in this case. One may still want a plot with both axes and a frame; e.g. `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey - I do not agree that this shows a bug.  Since `Frame` and `Axes` are controlled independently, putting `Frame -> True` in the `Show` has no effect on the default `Axes -> True` inherited from `p1`. However, since "Options explicitly specified in Show override those included in the graphics expression" then either `Axes -> False` or `Axes -> None` in the `Show` will override the default `Axes` setting from `p1`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay, You and Bob Hanlon make good arguments.  Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[{p1, p2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, L - 1}/L, {4.5, 10}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "L = 20", 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(l\), \(L\)]\)", 14, Bold], 
   Style["U", 14, Bold]}, Axes -> None]
```

yields the following

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: How easy! thanks a lot!!!